# Updating foreign keys in SQLServer like Access

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, ms-access, foreign-keys

I have a table, `Contacts`, with a primary key of `ContactID`, which is an identity column.  I have another table, `Person`, with a primary key of `PersonID` that is a foreign key to `ContactID`.  When I insert a record into `Person`, I would like `PersonID` to pull the corresponding identity from `ContactID` in `Contact`.

In Access, I simply make a query that references both tables, and it will fill in the foreign key column with the corresponding value in the identity (autonumber) column.

`SELECT Person.PersonID, Person.FirstName, Person.MiddleName, Person.LastName, Contact.ContactID, Contact.EmailAddress, Contact.PhoneNumber
FROM (Contact INNER JOIN Person ON Contact.ContactID = Person.PersonID);`

How can we achieve this in SQLServer 2008 R2?  I have been programming triggers to update the keys, but it seems like there ought to be a better way.

Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert to the first table, you use the `OUTPUT` clause to pull the identity value and then you can use it to insert to the child table.

You can also use `scope_identity()` to do the same thing, but OUTPUT is the preferred method. Do not under any circumstances use `@@Identity` as it often will give incorrect results and mess up your data integrity.

Look up how to use them in Books Online.

Comment: Let's define the query in my question as `qPerson`.  In Access, if I were to just use `INSERT INTO qPerson (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber) VALUES ("Bobort", "Bogobin", "N/A")`, the keys would automatically be filled in.  Is there a way to maintain this same simple syntax in SQLServer using triggers or some other builtin means rather than using an `OUTPUT` clause?